# Multiple call stack main threads in VSCode when running debug

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, callstack

I'm running an android emulator with Flutter in VSCode on Windows. When I run debug the call stack runs 2 main threads. Is this abnormal? I am getting emulator connections dropouts. With other (smaller) Flutter projects it doesn't run any threads.

[image]

Comment: Also getting this ... think it's causing issues with integration tests as well.

Comment: Hey, did you find the reason behind it?

Comment: @TecHaxter No i didn't unfortunately

Comment: First one is useless as I see, but I can't terminate neither of them.